# Error while executing xp_readerrorlog using OPENROWSET in SQL Server - querying remote data sources

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can you please help me to fix this query?

```
SELECT 
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI',
                'Server=.;Trusted_Connection=Yes;',
                'SET FMTONLY OFF;EXEC master.sys.xp_readerrorlog')
```

I get this error:

> Msg 11519, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sys.sp_describe_first_result_set, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 12]
> The metadata could not be determined because statement 'EXEC master.sys.xp_readerrorlog' invokes an extended stored procedure.

I have enabled Ad-Hoc Distributed Queries as well by using below query but getting same error.

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;

EXEC sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Comment: Why are you using `OPENROWSET` for this at all? Why not just call `xp_readerrorlog`? Why tag SQL Server 2008 *and* 2012?  What dose Maximum Segment Size have to do with any of this?

Comment: I want to load this data from all of my instances so using Openrowset, please let me know if any alternative option for remote data querying, i am getting same error xp_readerrorlog while executing this with parameters as well.

Comment: Have you tried using 4 part naming instead (and again, not using `OPENROWSET`)?

Comment: I have tried using full connecting string and not working ..can you please provide the query to try

Comment: `EXEC {Your Linked Server Name}.master.sys.xp_readerrorlog`...

Comment: Agreed, `OPENROWSET` is unnecessary here, just execute the procedure directly

Comment: I have 120 active instances and creating linked server for all of my 120 instances was risky and not possible now, We should use any of other remote server querying data method other than linked server  1. OPENQUERY 2.OPENROWSET 3.OPENDATASOURCE

Comment: Sounds like you should be using something else to connect to the instance and run the query then, @Nani . This has a strong smell of an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: @larnu we have 4 different types of methods to query remote data and here is the information about it.. https://www.sqlshack.com/querying-remote-data-sources-in-sql-server/  you are referring only Linked server but we have 3 other method.

Comment: @Larnu OPENROWSET was used for Querying remote data sources and i have mentioned clearly in my query. I think you have XY Problem of understanding the query.

Comment: Yes, you have asked Y: "How do I get `OPENROWSET` to work with `xp_readerrorlog`?" X would be "How do I consume the error logs from multiple different instances of SQL Server?"

Comment: Lol, maybe there was several ways to read error logs from different instances of SQL server but i am using OPENROWSET for all other processes which i had implemented already, so using same method for this also,, you mean to say this was not possible to read errors using openrowset ?

Comment: with result sets? `EXEC master.sys.xp_readerrorlog WITH RESULT SETS ((LogDate datetime, ProcessInfo nvarchar(500), ErrorText nvarchar(max)))`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `OPENROWSET` for an extended stored procedure. You could create a linked server

```sql
 EXEC {Your Linked Server Name}.master.sys.xp_readerrorlog;
```

But you say you have 120 instances. (Quite why you don't have management software for so many, is another question...) So you are better off using [Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/get-sqlerrorlog?view=sqlserver-ps) to do this. For example

```
Get-SqlErrorLog
   -Since LastMonth
   -ServerInstance "your","Server","Instances","Here"
```

You would probably want other code to filter and group the results, but you haven't shown what you want.

For example you could do something like this

```
Get-Content "ServerInstances.txt"
| Get-SqlErrorLog -After "2022-09-16 10:00:00"
| Where Source -eq "Backup"
```